# Return ComboBox as Boolean

Tags: c#, winforms

I know its not best practice to use a boolean for a comboBox but for this application which returns data a yes/no is all thats required. I'm trying to return whether its yes or no but am getting a warning 'possible unintended reference' Any help cleaning up the code is greatly appreciated.

```
public bool PlayDataToEnd
{
    get
    {
        return this.PlayDataToEnd.SelectedValue == "Yes";
    }
    set
    {
        this.PlayDataToEnd.SelectedValue = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because your property `PlayDataToEnd` has the same name as the `ComboBox`.

Comment: How about this.PlayDataToEnd.SelectedValue.ToString()?

Comment: Tried the ToString first but you cant covert bool to  string

Comment: Yes you can( didn't word the comment very well) but for method he suggested it wont let me via .ToString()

Comment: if you want to get a true or false from the selected combobox item(if i understood you the items are all yes and no),just make a normal boolean property and place a selectedindexchanged event and there you assign that boolean property with an expresion like: boolprop = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "yes" ? true : false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your internal `ComboBox` is named `playDataToEndCombo`:

```
public bool PlayDataToEnd
{
    get
    {
        return playDataToEndCombo.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Yes";
    }
    set
    {
        playDataToEndCombo.SelectedValue = value ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

I think you should use `Index` with a convention: `0 for Yes` and `1 for No`:

```
public bool PlayDataToEnd
{
    get
    {
        return playDataToEndCombo.SelectedIndex == 0;
    }
    set
    {
        playDataToEndCombo.SelectedIndex = value ?  0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: With that i get many syntax errors and Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: What line? I suppose `PlayDataToEnd` is your `ComboBox`.

Comment: The errors are coming from ? : 0 : 1; I get invalid expression terms ; expected and the error message I posted above

Comment: @KingKing: you have an extra colon after the question mark in the ternary operator in your last example.

Comment: this.playdataToEndCombo.SelectedIndex  = value ? : 0 : 1; should be a complete match

Comment: @user2637869 what do you mean? That expression is very simple, if the `value` assigned to the property `PlayDataToEnd` is `true`, the `SelectedIndex` of the combobox `playDataToEndCombo` will be `0` which means `Yes`, otherwise it will be `1` which means `No`.

Comment: I mean that for whatever reason although my code is a carbon match apart from variables etc its throwing errors at me, Ill work on it some more, thank for the help

Comment: @user2637869: you still have that extra colon after the question mark. That *has* to go away.